# qsub pbs doesn't show error and output log, even forcing the path

Tags: output, pbs, qsub

when I run code using qsub and pbs script, the log and error files are not shown.
I have also tried to add the path of error and log file, but without succes

```
#PBS -N example_job 
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -q shortp
#PBS -V
##PBS -v BATCH_NUM_PROC_TOT=16
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=4
#PBS -e $HOME/error.txt
#PBS -o $HOME/otput.txt
```

Do you know how can I solve the problem ?
Thanks a lot